# gradle custom properties and println

Tags: gradle

I'm very new to gradle so I'm trying to make sense of it. I'm trying to print the custom properties using `println` and it works when I just use the property.  But as soon as I put it in a string it fails and I'm not sure what is going on.

**gradle.properties** looks like this:

```
version = '2.0'
description = 'Project Description'

project.ext {
    winADTSDKManager = 'SDK Manager.exe'
    winADTSDKManagerPath = 'C:/Projects/WinSDKEnv/sdk/adt'
}
```

in **build.gradle** I try to run the code:

```
task androidSDKManager << { 
    description = 'Run Android SDK Manager'

    println project.ext.winADTSDKManagerPath
    println 'Starting: $project.ext.winADTSDKManagerPath'
}
```

The output looks like this:

c:\Projects\Prototypes\STouchGradle>gradle androidSDKManager
:androidSDKManager
'C:/Projects/WinSDKEnv/sdk/adt'
Starting: $project.ext.winADTSDKManagerPath

The second `println` statement is not printing the path like the one above. Any ideas on what is wrong with what im doing?

**Update: 7/27/2014**
OK I figured it out. I need to use double quotes like this
    println "Starting: $project.ext.winADTSDKManagerPath"

Comment: Also, `ext.` should be omitted when reading an extra property, and `description` needs to be set at configuration time (not in a task action).

Comment: So i would just access for example project.ext.winADTSDKManagerPath as project.winADTSDKManagerPath?

Comment: Correct. `project.` is redundant as well.